# If all elements don't have a particular class, then apply styles

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a list of elements with the class name of `.box`. Sometimes, an element will have an extra class, but I will not know which element has it.

Is there a way to check if all elements of `.box` don't have `.extraClass`, then apply styles to `.box`, but if any elements of `.box` has the class `.extraClass`, then don't apply the css style?

I want to do it using css only.

#### JSFiddle

```js
var toggleClass = document.getElementById('toggleClass'),
  box = document.getElementsByClassName('box'),
  randomNumber = -1;

toggleClass.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (randomNumber !== -1) box[randomNumber].classList.remove('extraClass');
  randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
  box[randomNumber].classList.toggle('extraClass');
});
removeClass.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (randomNumber !== -1) box[randomNumber].classList.remove('extraClass');
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.box {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
  list-style-type: none;
}
/*If all of '.box' DOES'T have the class '.extraClass`; make background of '.box' pink*/

.box {
  background-color: pink;
}
.extraClass {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul id="wrapper">
  <li class="box"></li>
  <li class="box"></li>
  <li class="box"></li>
  <li class="box"></li>
  <li class="box"></li>
  <li class="box"></li>
  <li class="box"></li>
  <li class="box"></li>
  <li class="box"></li>
  <li class="box"></li>
</ul>

<button id="toggleClass">Toggle Class</button>

<button id="removeClass">Remove Class</button>
```

Comment: I don't believe you can perform this sort of DOM checking logic with CSS only

Comment: I think this is the closest you'll get with just CSS, unless you use a hack of some sort:https://jsfiddle.net/o2puqddL/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you should use a third CSS class that you also add to the parent when you add `.extraClass`-- using just those two could get cumbersome. As an example, here's some sample styling that you could use:

```
#wrapper:not(.disableStyling) .box {
  background: red;
}
```

This way, whenever you add that `.extraClass` to a box, you also add the `.disableStyling` class to the wrapper. It might make it a bit easier to follow

EDIT:

Here's the js segment you need to change:

```
var toggleClass = document.getElementById('toggleClass'),
  box = document.getElementsByClassName('box'),
  wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper'),
  randomNumber = -1;

toggleClass.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (randomNumber !== -1) box[randomNumber].classList.remove('extraClass');
  randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
  box[randomNumber].classList.toggle('extraClass');
  var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName("box");
  var disabled = false;

  for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++)
    if (boxes[i].classList.contains("extraClass")) disabled = true;
  if (disabled)
    wrapper.classList.add("disableStyling");
  else
    wrapper.classList.remove("disableStyling");
});
removeClass.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (randomNumber !== -1) {
    box[randomNumber].classList.remove('extraClass');
    wrapper.classList.toggle('disableStyling');
  }
});
```

Comment: I want to select all classes only if there isn't .extraClass. If there is, then I don't want to apply the css style to any elements.

Comment: @Horay that's what my solution does lol. You should probably be able to figure out the js... It's one for loop and extremely similar to what you've already wrote, I assumed you'd be alright

Comment: This is a clever solution. But the question was unclear about dynamically adding new classes. In fact, it specifically says: *using CSS only*. If a scripted solution is allowed, this whole thing can be resolved quickly with JS/jQuery.

Comment: @Michael_B well considering you can't do it with pure CSS, I thought I'd offer an alternative solution

Comment: @Wade Oh. Oops. Can you please update the jsfiddle. I'm not exactly sure I know what to change. Thanks

Comment: @Horay currently on my phone so I can't test it, but I added a bit of sample code to my answer-- I think it should work. As long as the browser you're using has the contains method on arrays. Otherwise you have to use a for loop to iterate over the class list as well

Comment: @Wade Thanks! I tried it, but it doesn't work: https://jsfiddle.net/rxpf5kL0/ So basically, the tiles should be green, but if `.disableStyling` is applied, all `.box` should be pink.

Comment: @Horay you had a couple spelling errors haha, here's the updated version (I hope? I'll update this post too) https://jsfiddle.net/rxpf5kL0/1/

Comment: @Horay I tested i though and it works. The main errors in yours were you didn't initialize the boxes variable, and also the wrapper CSS selector has to be an id (i.e. It has to be #wrapper, not .wrapper)

Comment: Thank you! This is actually a pretty smart answer. And it works, lol!

Comment: @Horay haha no problem. I've found many of my CSS selector problems can be solved by simply adding a flag class like this :)

Answer (score 1):

Vanilla CSS doesn't quite have logical operations like that... You'll need to use JavaScript unless you want to logically work out some kind of static solution.

Here a solution with jQuery: https://jsfiddle.net/d748Lxx7/

Note the `!`, that inverses it (otherwise it would look be looking to return true).

Comment: "Vanilla CSS doesn't have logical operations." Sure it does - the :not() pseudo. It's not a problem of not having logical operations, but a problem of where the existing logical operations are applicable (in the current standard, it's very limited).

Comment: I misspoke then, is "conditional operations" the right terminology?

Comment: It's hard to explain, I think, since CSS selectors are quite distinct from your run-of-the-mill programming language. There is nothing in the selector grammar that precludes negating, say, a `#wrapper > .box.extraClass` expression, and indeed the upcoming standard provides such a feature in the form of `#wrapper:not(:has(> .box.extraClass))` (which happens to work in jQuery). The feature just isn't there yet.